# Compute Fractions of Amounts Over Intervals of Time

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, forecasting

I'm forecasting revenue by fiscal year (not calendar year) for contracts with start dates and either lengths of time or end dates or both. My method involves finding the fraction of the contract which exists in each fiscal year and applying the total contract value (represented by `amounts` in the sample code). This gives the fraction of the contract value for that fiscal year.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

FY16 <- interval("2015-10-01", "2016-09-30")
FY17 <- interval("2016-10-01", "2017-09-30")
FY18 <- interval("2017-10-01", "2018-09-30")
FY19 <- interval("2018-10-01", "2019-09-30")
FY20 <- interval("2019-10-01", "2020-09-30")
FY21 <- interval("2020-10-01", "2021-09-30")
FY22 <- interval("2021-10-01", "2022-09-30")
FY23 <- interval("2022-10-01", "2023-09-30")
FY24 <- interval("2023-10-01", "2024-09-30")
FY25 <- interval("2024-10-01", "2025-09-30")
FY26 <- interval("2025-10-01", "2026-09-30")
FY27 <- interval("2026-10-01", "2027-09-30")
FY28 <- interval("2027-10-01", "2028-09-30")
FY29 <- interval("2028-10-01", "2029-09-30")
FY30 <- interval("2029-10-01", "2030-09-30")
FY31 <- interval("2030-10-01", "2031-09-30")
FY32 <- interval("2031-10-01", "2032-09-30")

data <- tibble(startDates = c("2018-04-01", "2025-09-17", "2021-07-21", "2026-11-17"),
               years = c(5,3,3,2),
               amounts = c(350000, 1200000, 7500000, 130000),
               surcharge = c(0.035, 0.04, 0.375, 0.05))

data <- as.data.frame(data)%>%
  mutate(startDates =as.POSIXct(`startDates`),
         endDate = `startDates`%m+%years(years),
         contractInterval = interval(startDates, endDate),
         `Days in Contract` = startDates%--%endDate/ddays(1),
         `FY16 Interval` = intersect(FY16, contractInterval),
         `FY17 Interval` = intersect(FY17, contractInterval),
         `FY18 Interval` = intersect(FY18, contractInterval),
         `FY19 Interval` = intersect(FY19, contractInterval),
         `FY20 Interval` = intersect(FY20, contractInterval),
         `FY21 Interval` = intersect(FY21, contractInterval),
         #and so on to FY32
         `Days in FY16` = int_start(`FY16 Interval`)%--%int_end(`FY16 Interval`)/ddays(1),
         `Days in FY17` = int_start(`FY17 Interval`)%--%int_end(`FY17 Interval`)/ddays(1),
         `Days in FY18` = int_start(`FY18 Interval`)%--%int_end(`FY18 Interval`)/ddays(1),
         `Days in FY19` = int_start(`FY19 Interval`)%--%int_end(`FY19 Interval`)/ddays(1),
         `Days in FY20` = int_start(`FY20 Interval`)%--%int_end(`FY20 Interval`)/ddays(1),
         `Days in FY21` = int_start(`FY21 Interval`)%--%int_end(`FY21 Interval`)/ddays(1),
         #and so on to FY32
         `FY16 Amount` = amounts*`Days in FY16`/`Days in Contract`,
         `FY17 Amount` = amounts*`Days in FY17`/`Days in Contract`,
         `FY18 Amount` = amounts*`Days in FY18`/`Days in Contract`,
         `FY19 Amount` = amounts*`Days in FY19`/`Days in Contract`,
         `FY20 Amount` = amounts*`Days in FY20`/`Days in Contract`,
         `FY21 Amount` = amounts*`Days in FY21`/`Days in Contract`,
         #and so on to FY32
         `FY16 Surcharge Amount` = surcharge*`FY16 Amount`,
         `FY17 Surcharge Amount` = surcharge*`FY17 Amount`,
         `FY18 Surcharge Amount` = surcharge*`FY18 Amount`,
         `FY19 Surcharge Amount` = surcharge*`FY19 Amount`,
         `FY20 Surcharge Amount` = surcharge*`FY20 Amount`,
         `FY21 Surcharge Amount` = surcharge*`FY21 Amount`
         #and so on to FY32
         ) 

data.summary <- data%>%
  summarise(`FY16 Total` = sum(`FY16 Amount`, na.rm = T),
            `FY17 Total` = sum(`FY17 Amount`, na.rm = T),
            `FY18 Total` = sum(`FY18 Amount`, na.rm = T),
            `FY19 Total` = sum(`FY19 Amount`, na.rm = T),
            `FY20 Total` = sum(`FY20 Amount`, na.rm = T),
            `FY21 Total` = sum(`FY21 Amount`, na.rm = T),
            # and so on to FY32
            `FY16 Surcharge Total` = sum(`FY16 Surcharge Amount`, na.rm = T),
            `FY17 Surcharge Total` = sum(`FY17 Surcharge Amount`, na.rm = T),
            `FY18 Surcharge Total` = sum(`FY18 Surcharge Amount`, na.rm = T),
            `FY19 Surcharge Total` = sum(`FY19 Surcharge Amount`, na.rm = T),
            `FY20 Surcharge Total` = sum(`FY20 Surcharge Amount`, na.rm = T),
            `FY21 Surcharge Total` = sum(`FY21 Surcharge Amount`, na.rm = T),
            #and so on to FY32
            )
```

It's pretty straightforward and works fine, but it's incredibly tedious to code! What's worse is that my method has garnered attention and will likely be deployed across all regions and divisions. Great news, right? Not when I have to code every fiscal year separately in both the preparation and the summarization. Is my life to be reduced to copying and pasting and changing two digits? Please say it isn't. **How can I do this more efficiently?** I welcome all suggestions and thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd pivot from wide to long, incorporating the `FY16` (etc) component of the variable name into a distinct column, then you'd do things like `summarize(.by = FY, Total = sum(Amount))`. Your sample code fails for me, `! \`FY16 Interval\` must be size 4 or 1, not 0.`

Comment: In general, I think deployed code with dplyr or deployed code with base R is not a huge issue; the concern for me is typically _readability_ and _maintainability_. Future-me often curses present-me because of lack of comments/documentation, unclear rationale for obscure (and often "clever") code blocks, etc. Whether or not anybody else will be looking at your code, "future you" will appreciate clear and readable code.

Comment: @r2evans: Apologies for the failure. I removed a space at the last minute, causing some variable to cease to exist. I've corrected the issue.

Comment: Your edit changes nothing, I still get the `must be size 4 or 1, not 0` error. Please try your code on the sample data you provided. If it does not error, then ... I'm on R-4.3.2, dplyr_1.1.4, lubridate_1.9.3 (on linux using emacs/ess, unlikely to be relevant).

Comment: Really!? There was a space in FY 16 Amount (and FY 17, FY 18, etc.) which has been changed to FY16 Amount (FY17 Amount, FY18 Amount, etc.). I got that error before the change, as well; it runs fine now though. I'm using R 4.2.2 with RStudio 12.0.353 on a 64-bit x86 platform, loading lubridate 1.9.3 & dplyr 1.1.4. I agree that is highly unlikely to matter but I'm curious as to why you're still getting that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest thinking about this in a "long data" way instead of a "wide data" way: it is more dynamic, much shorter code, and allows for easily changing to fewer or more fiscal years without much effort.

First, these are the fiscal years I think we're interested in covering:

```r
FYs <- tibble(FYstart = as.Date("2015-10-01") %m+% years(0:15)) %>%
  mutate(
    FYend = FYstart %m+% years(1) - 1,
    FY = paste0("FY", substr(year(FYend), 3, 4))
  )
```

From there, we'll start with your initial four columns, then join on `FYs` and filter/mutate, then summarize.

```r
data <- 
  tibble(startDates = as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-01", "2025-09-17", "2021-07-21", "2026-11-17")),
         years = c(5,3,3,2),
         amounts = c(350000, 1200000, 7500000, 130000),
         surcharge = c(0.035, 0.04, 0.375, 0.05)) %>%
  mutate(endDates = startDates %m+% years(years)) %>%
  left_join(FYs, join_by(overlaps(startDates, endDates, FYstart, FYend))) |> # thanks @JonSpring for this recommendation
  mutate(
    FYstart = pmax(startDates, FYstart),
    FYend   = pmin(endDates, FYend),
    `Days in Contract` = as.numeric(endDates - startDates, units = "days"),
    `Days in FY` = as.numeric(FYend - FYstart, units = "days"),
    `FY Amount` = amounts * `Days in FY` / `Days in Contract`,
    `FY Surcharge Amount` = surcharge * `FY Amount`
  )
data
# # A tibble: 17 × 12
#    startDates          years amounts surcharge endDates            FYstart             FYend               FY    `Days in Contract` `Days in FY` `FY Amount` `FY Surcharge Amount`
#    <dttm>              <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>              <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>                 <dbl>
#  1 2018-04-01 00:00:00     5  350000     0.035 2023-04-01 00:00:00 2018-04-01 00:00:00 2018-09-29 20:00:00 FY18                1826        182.       34853.                 1220.
#  2 2018-04-01 00:00:00     5  350000     0.035 2023-04-01 00:00:00 2018-09-30 20:00:00 2019-09-29 20:00:00 FY19                1826        364        69770.                 2442.
#  3 2018-04-01 00:00:00     5  350000     0.035 2023-04-01 00:00:00 2019-09-30 20:00:00 2020-09-29 20:00:00 FY20                1826        365        69962.                 2449.
#  4 2018-04-01 00:00:00     5  350000     0.035 2023-04-01 00:00:00 2020-09-30 20:00:00 2021-09-29 20:00:00 FY21                1826        364        69770.                 2442.
#  5 2018-04-01 00:00:00     5  350000     0.035 2023-04-01 00:00:00 2021-09-30 20:00:00 2022-09-29 20:00:00 FY22                1826        364        69770.                 2442.
#  6 2018-04-01 00:00:00     5  350000     0.035 2023-04-01 00:00:00 2022-09-30 20:00:00 2023-04-01 00:00:00 FY23                1826        182.       34917.                 1222.
#  7 2025-09-17 00:00:00     3 1200000     0.04  2028-09-17 00:00:00 2025-09-17 00:00:00 2025-09-29 20:00:00 FY25                1096         12.8      14051.                  562.
#  8 2025-09-17 00:00:00     3 1200000     0.04  2028-09-17 00:00:00 2025-09-30 20:00:00 2026-09-29 20:00:00 FY26                1096        364       398540.                15942.
#  9 2025-09-17 00:00:00     3 1200000     0.04  2028-09-17 00:00:00 2026-09-30 20:00:00 2027-09-29 20:00:00 FY27                1096        364       398540.                15942.
# 10 2025-09-17 00:00:00     3 1200000     0.04  2028-09-17 00:00:00 2027-09-30 20:00:00 2028-09-17 00:00:00 FY28                1096        352.      385584.                15423.
# 11 2021-07-21 00:00:00     3 7500000     0.375 2024-07-21 00:00:00 2021-07-21 00:00:00 2021-09-29 20:00:00 FY21                1096         70.8     484717.               181769.
# 12 2021-07-21 00:00:00     3 7500000     0.375 2024-07-21 00:00:00 2021-09-30 20:00:00 2022-09-29 20:00:00 FY22                1096        364      2490876.               934078.
# 13 2021-07-21 00:00:00     3 7500000     0.375 2024-07-21 00:00:00 2022-09-30 20:00:00 2023-09-29 20:00:00 FY23                1096        364      2490876.               934078.
# 14 2021-07-21 00:00:00     3 7500000     0.375 2024-07-21 00:00:00 2023-09-30 20:00:00 2024-07-21 00:00:00 FY24                1096        294.     2013002.               754876.
# 15 2026-11-17 00:00:00     2  130000     0.05  2028-11-17 00:00:00 2026-11-17 00:00:00 2027-09-29 20:00:00 FY27                 731        317.       56338.                 2817.
# 16 2026-11-17 00:00:00     2  130000     0.05  2028-11-17 00:00:00 2027-09-30 20:00:00 2028-09-29 20:00:00 FY28                 731        365        64911.                 3246.
# 17 2026-11-17 00:00:00     2  130000     0.05  2028-11-17 00:00:00 2028-09-30 20:00:00 2028-11-17 00:00:00 FY29                 731         47.2       8395.                  420.
```

The summarizing is really direct, too:

```r
data.summary <- data %>%
  summarize(
    .by = FY,
    across(c(`FY Amount`, `FY Surcharge Amount`), ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
           .names = "{.col} Total")
  )
data.summary
# # A tibble: 12 × 3
#    FY    `FY Amount Total` `FY Surcharge Amount Total`
#    <chr>             <dbl>                       <dbl>
#  1 FY18             34853.                       1220.
#  2 FY19             69770.                       2442.
#  3 FY20             69962.                       2449.
#  4 FY21            554487.                     184211.
#  5 FY22           2560646.                     936520.
#  6 FY23           2525793.                     935301.
#  7 FY25             14051.                        562.
#  8 FY26            398540.                      15942.
#  9 FY27            454878.                      18758.
# 10 FY28            450495.                      18669.
# 11 FY24           2013002.                     754876.
# 12 FY29              8395.                        420.
```

Comment: This is exactly the sort of suggestion I was hoping to see. Thank you r2evans! I know we're not supposed to thank people in comments, but my momma raised me better than that. Naturally, I need to implement your solution before accepted the answer, but I wanted to express my gratitude beforehand.

Comment: I think you could use `left_join(FYs, join_by(overlaps(startDates, endDates, FYstart, FYend))) %>%` as a simpler version of the cross-join + filter steps. I get the same output. If the data were much larger, like millions of observations, then I presume it would be more performant, too.

Comment: Good point, thanks @JonSpring, I haven't worked `overlaps` into my lexicon yet ..

Comment: (I don't think you need the filter step any more, btw)